# How to genericise the creation of a Predicate for a TableView's FilteredList in JavaFX8?

Tags: generics, javafx, tableview, javafx-8

A question from an experienced programmer who's still relatively new to Java.

I've created a prototype of a class that adds Excel-like data filters to columns in a `TableView`.  I'm now making it generic so that it will work with any `TableView` and am stuck with how to "genericise" the creation of `Predicate`s.

In my prototype (where I've hard-coded everything), I call a `createPredicate()` method for a `String` "Value" column, for example, like this:

```
createPredicate(TableViewModel::getTvValue);
```

and in the `createPredicate()` method, I set the `Predicate` like this:

```
private void createPredicate(Function<TableViewModel, String> columnGetter) {
    //...
    final String filter = "some value";
    Predicate<TableViewModel> predicate = tvm -> columnGetter.apply(tvm).contains(filter);
    //...
}
```

How can I make both the call to the method and the method itself generic, so that they will work for any `TableColumn`?

I'm stuck in two places.  Firstly, how to get the getter for a `TableColumn` so I can pass it to the `createPredicate()` method ...

```
//Get a column
TableColumn<S, T> col = (TableColumn<S, T>) table.getColumns().get(0);

//Set a predicate based on the column
//==>STUCK HERE:  How do I get the getter for the column?
createPredicate(S::<WHAT_GOES_HERE?>);
```

... and secondly, how to make the `contains()` generic.  I'm currently getting a "cannot find symbol method contains(T)" compiler error.

```
private void createPredicate(Function<S, T> columnGetter) {

    final T filter = (T) "some value";
    //STUCK HERE:  How to genericise the contains?
    Predicate<S> predicate = tvm -> columnGetter.apply(tvm).contains(filter);

}
```

Thanks in advance.  If it helps, here is a MVCE. I'm using JavaFX8 (JDK1.8.0_181) and NetBeans 8.2.

The (bare bones!) **TestColumnFilter.java** class:

```
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;

public class TestColumnFilter<S, T> {

    public TestColumnFilter(TableView<S> table) {

        //Get a column
        TableColumn<S, T> col = (TableColumn<S, T>) table.getColumns().get(0);

        //Set a predicate based on the column
        //STUCK HERE:  How to get the getter for the column?
        createPredicate(S::<WHAT_GOES_HERE?>);

    }

    private void createPredicate(Function<S, T> columnGetter) {

        final T filter = (T) "some value";
        //STUCK HERE:  How to genericise the contains?  
        //Currently getting a "cannot find symbol method contains(T)" compiler error
        Predicate<S> predicate = tvm -> columnGetter.apply(tvm).contains(filter);

    }

    public static <S, T> TestColumnFilter<S, T> createColumnFiltersForTableView(TableView<S> table) {

        return new TestColumnFilter<>(table);

    }

}
```

and **Test55.java**, a dummy class that uses TestColumnFilter.java.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test55 extends Application {

    private Parent createContent() {

        TableView<TableViewModel> table = new TableView<>();
        TableColumn<TableViewModel, String> valueCol = new TableColumn<>("Value");
        valueCol.setCellValueFactory(cb -> cb.getValue().tvValueProperty());

        table.getColumns().addAll(Arrays.asList(valueCol));

        TestColumnFilter.createColumnFiltersForTableView(table);

        BorderPane content = new BorderPane(table);

        return content;
    }

    private class TableViewModel {

        private final StringProperty tvValue;

        public TableViewModel(
            String tvValue
        ) {
            this.tvValue = new SimpleStringProperty(tvValue);
        }

        public String getTvValue() {return tvValue.get().trim();}
        public void setTvValue(String tvValue) {this.tvValue.set(tvValue);}
        public StringProperty tvValueProperty() {return tvValue;}

    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setScene(new Scene(createContent()));
        stage.setTitle("Test");
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the current design would eventually work out well.

I'm going to assume that you could set filters on multiple columns, and the `TableView` should show the results based on *all* filters.

You could try this approach:

```
public class TableViewFilter<S> {
    private final TableView<S> tableView;
    private final FilteredList<S> filteredItems;
    private final ObservableList<Function<S, Boolean>> conditions;

    public TableViewFilter(TableView<S> tableView, ObservableList<S> items) {
        this.tableView = tableView;
        this.filteredItems = new FilteredList<>(items);
        this.tableView.setItems(filteredItems ).

        this.conditions = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        this.filteredItems.predicateProperty().bind(
            Bindings.createObjectBinding(this::generatePredicate, this.conditions));
    }

    public static <S> TableViewFilter<S> forTableView(TableView<S> tableView) {
        return new TableViewFilter<>(tableView);
    }

    public void addCondition(Function<S, Boolean> condition) {
        conditions.add(condition);
    }

    private Predicate<S> generatePredicate() {
        return item -> {
            return conditions.stream().map(func -> func.apply(item)).allMatch(Boolean.TRUE::equals);
        };
    }
}

TableView<TableViewModel> table = new TableView<>();
    TableColumn<TableViewModel, String> valueCol = new TableColumn<>("Value");
    valueCol.setCellValueFactory(cb -> cb.getValue().tvValueProperty());

    table.getColumns().addAll(Arrays.asList(valueCol));

    ObservableList<TableViewModel> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    items.addAll(/*items*/);

    //TestColumnFilter.createColumnFiltersForTableView(table);
    TableViewFilter filter = TableViewFilter.forTableView(table, items); // Keep a reference if you need to add more conditions later
    filter.addCondition(item -> item.getTvValue().contains("filtered string"));

    BorderPane content = new BorderPane(table);

    return content;
}
```

Notice that the condition does not depend on a particular `TableColumn`. It is easier to filter using the underlying data (i.e. `TableViewModel`).

Comment: Hello, Jai, many thanks for your reply. Yes, your assumption is correct – more than one column could be filtered and there could be multiple filter values for each column. The `TableView` would show the result from all filters. I can see how your code works and will give it a go. Please give me a few days to play with it, though, as I’m not familiar with some of the syntax you’ve used and will have to do some research. One Q: Is there a way of getting the getter for a `TableColumn`? I tried getting its cell value factory but couldn’t work out where to go from there. Cheers!

Comment: @GreenZebra Your approach is weird because each `TableColumn` here simply represents the schema of the table. When you set a cell factory for a particular column, you are telling the column *how* to get values for each row of the table. Since the cell factory is used to determine the values of **cells**, it is impossible to reverse this to retrieve a "getter" function that is common throughout the whole *column*.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, Jai. I now understand why my approach is weird and wouldn’t work well. So, I’ve decided to start from scratch (again!) and will try your approach. Will see how I go with it. Thanks for the hints. Cheers.

Comment: Hello, Jai. Just letting you know I was able to get your code working.  I changed `this.tableView.setItems(items).` to `this.tableView.setItems(filteredItems);` and got it filtering one column successfully.  Now to get it working for multiple columns each with multiple values. Cheers again!

Comment: @GreenZebra Nice to know it worked. This should work for multiple conditions. Note that my example has used the "AND" logic to join all the conditions (i.e. each row has to meet all conditions in order not to be filtered out) via `Stream::allMatch()`. If you want entries to be filtered out if *any* of the conditions is met, then you can change it to `Stream::anyMatch()`.

Comment: just a note: tableColumn has methods getCellData/getCellObservableValue that can be used in per-column filtering

Comment: @kleopatra How do you filter using that? Manually removing the data for that row if that cell's value matches?

Comment: just the same as taking the whole item for the predicate: for each item, let the per-column predicate decide based on the cellData as returned by the column - for several columns and/or the per-column predicates

Comment: @Jai Hello Jai, my column filter finally works! I couldn’t figure out how to combine `allMatch()` and `anyMatch()` to do what I needed (which was to OR values for each column and then AND the results of the ORs), but your approach of using an `ObservableList` worked a treat. I created ORed predicates for each column and stored them in the `ObservableList`. When the “OK” button was clicked, I ANDed them together and used the result as the predicate for the `FilteredList`. I learned a lot about `stream().map()` in the process, so thank you as always for your help. It’s much appreciated!